# Upgrading dataloder salesforce on macos for the log4j

Tags: java, admin, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade the dataloader to mitigate the log4j vulnerability.

I have tried to follow the steps on the github repo but i am getting this error trying to build with "./dlbuilder.sh -n"

```
./dlbuilder.sh: line 37: mvn: command not found
removing JndiLookup.class from 2.17.0

zip error: Nothing to do! (/Users/riekus/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.0/log4j-core-2.17.0.jar)

zip error: Nothing to do! (/Users/riekus/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.0/log4j-core-2.17.0.jar)
./dlbuilder.sh: line 48: mvn: command not found
find: ./target: No such file or directory
```

I am also trying just to download the latest. According to the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_install_mac.htm):
I should be able to find the dataloader install under a org / setup/ datalaoder but searching for dataloader i only get dataloader.io

Is there any concise howto for upgrading dataloader or freshly installing the latest?

Comment: Looks like the documentation on that project is in a state of disrepair. Do you have `maven` installed?

Comment: here is a link that can help - https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/v53.0.2

Comment: For the download link in setup, search 'Data Loader' with a space - quick find takes search terms very literally.  Of note, I don't know if that's the latest version with the Log4J vuln mitigations.

Comment: thanks guys, worked with the link from @kurunve

Comment: Note that if you go to Setup | Data Management | Data Loader in your org you will get version 53.02; If you type in `dataloader` in Setup search, you get dataloader.io, but if you type in `Data Loader` in search you get what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest Data Loader (53.02 - includes the log4j patch) directly from the org

- `Setup | Data Management | Data Loader`
- If you search in setup for `dataloader`, you get back `dataloader.io`.
- If you search in Setup for `data loader` (note space), you get `Data Loader`. *Just one more example where setup search term needs to be precise*